# how to create year/month/day structure when uploading files with django

Tags: python, django

am using a basic imagefield and upload_to function to point to my destination folder. I was wondering if there is something i can use to create folder structure with year/month/day on upload date or something..

regards,

Answer (score 18, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#imagefield

For example, say your **MEDIA_ROOT** is set to `'/home/media'`, and `upload_to` is set to '`photos/%Y/%m/%d'`.
The `'%Y/%m/%d'` part of `upload_to` is strftime formatting.

1. `%Y` is the four-digit year.
2. `%m` is the two-digit month.
3. `%d` is the two-digit day.

If you upload a file on Jan. 15, 2007, it will be saved in the directory
`/home/media/photos/2007/01/15`.

Answer (score 8):

fist of all, check this out: http://scottbarnham.com/blog/2007/07/31/uploading-images-to-a-dynamic-path-with-django/ look for "Attempt 4" (control + f on the page) so you can see how to create a function for a dynamic upload.

then, to create your path, you have to use the datetime module:

```
from datetime import date
today = date.now()
today_path = today.strftime("%Y/%m/%d") ## this will create something like "2011/08/30"
```

you now have your path, better if you join it with your base path and filename (base path is your images folder)

```
os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, today_path, filename)
```

this will give you something like `/path/to/images/2011/08/30/filename.jpg`

The first link is really important.